# How to remove a message in an array that is part of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Can anyone tell me why this code will not delete messages from the messages property of this object?

```js
var facebookProfile = {
  name: "Bill Smith",
  friends: 0,
  messages: ["msg"],
  postMessage: function(message) {
    message = "hello";
    facebookProfile.messages.push(message);
  },
  deleteMessage: function(index) {
    index = 0;
    facebookProfile.messages.splice(index);
  },
  addFriend: function() {
    facebookProfile.friends = facebookProfile.friends + 1;
  },
  removeFriend: function() {
    facebookProfile.friends = facebookProfile.friends - 1;
  }
};
```

Comment: Why are you always setting `index = 0;`? What's the use of the parameter then?

Comment: I could really set it to anything. It's an assignment for a course where the only requirement is that deleteMessage does exactly that. When I try this code, I get the message that it does not delete messages, but it doesn't say why.

Comment: users here are very quick to say it has been answered, but if you look at my code, and read the comments, I have already tried splice.

Comment: Add a `console.log(facebookProfile.messages)` before and after calling `deleteMessage` and then post your console output.

Comment: Thank you, Silent! I actually went ahead and removed index=0 and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

```
facebookProfile.messages.splice(index,1);
```

above code should work and fix your problem. In splice function, number of elements to be deleted is zero by default and hence you have to mention that too

Comment: I'll try it! thank you..

Comment: Nope. Sorry, still the same message, that the code does not remove messages from the array.

Comment: where are you trying this?

Comment: In a proprietary IDE for a course I am taking on an online platform. I am not impressed with the platform.

Comment: Just use the code in your browser console. It worked for me. Deleted the first element of messages array as its index is set to 0. Maybe some IDE problem?

Comment: No problem mate :)